# Unity throwing IL2CPP build error at run time when building for Android? 2018.4.5f1

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, 64-bit, il2cpp

I'm trying to build a project for deployment to the play store, but getting the dreaded IL2CPP errors at build-time.  Below are the errors, **both relate to the same file il2cppcore.dll**.  Any help is appreciated.

Unity version 2018.4.5f1

I have...

- checked the Build App Bundle (Play Store) box
- added NDK r16b 64-bit path.
- have Android Studio & sdk tools installed and Unity sees recognizes them and succeeds building with mono for x32
- have target platform API 22 installed via Android studio and set in Player Settings.
- have ARMv7 and ARMv64 checked, and x86 unchecked in player settings
- Have "Strip Engine Code" Unchecked in settings
- I had to opt into Allowing clang++ and several other programs in NDK to run via Mac > System Prefs > Privacy & Security when I first downloaded it and pointed Unity to it's location.

```
Failed running /Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/il2cpp/build/il2cppcore/il2cppcore.dll --convert-to-cpp --emit-null-checks --enable-array-bounds-check --dotnetprofile="unityaot" --compile-cpp --libil2cpp-static --platform="Android" --architecture="ARMv7" --configuration="Release" --outputpath="/Users/db639c/Desktop/Projects/Unity 10ft/Data Testing v2/Temp/StagingArea/assets/bin/Data/Native/armeabi-v7a/libil2cpp.so" --cachedirectory="/Users/db639c/Desktop/Projects/Unity 10ft/Data Testing v2/Assets/../Library/il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a/il2cpp_cache" --additional-include-directories="/Applications/Unity/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/bdwgc/include" --additional-include-directories="/Applications/Unity/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/libil2cpp/include" --tool-chain-path="/Users/db639c/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/android-ndk-r16b" --map-file-parser="/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Tools/MapFileParser/MapFileParser" --directory="/Users/db639c/Desktop/Projects/Unity 10ft/Data Testing v2/Temp/StagingArea/assets/bin/Data/Managed" --generatedcppdir="/Users/db639c/Desktop/Projects/Unity 10ft/Data Testing v2/Temp/StagingArea/Il2Cpp/il2cppOutput" 

stdout:
Building libil2cpp.so with AndroidToolChain
    Output directory: /Users/db639c/Desktop/Projects/Unity 10ft/Data Testing v2/Temp/StagingArea/assets/bin/Data/Native/armeabi-v7a
    Cache directory: /Users/db639c/Desktop/Projects/Unity 10ft/Data Testing v2/Library/il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a/il2cpp_cache
il2cpp.exe didn't catch exception: Unity.IL2CPP.Building.BuilderFailedException: 

Invocation was: Executable: /Users/db639c/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++
Arguments: -DNET_4_0 -DUNITY_AOT -DGC_NOT_DLL -DRUNTIME_IL2CPP -DLINUX -DANDROID -DPLATFORM_ANDROID -D__linux__ -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -I"/Applications/Unity/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/bdwgc/include" -I"/Applications/Unity/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/libil2cpp/include" -I"/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/il2cpp/libil2cpp" -I"/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/il2cpp/external/boehmgc/include" -I"/Users/db639c/Desktop/Projects/Unity 10ft/Data Testing v2/Temp/StagingArea/Il2Cpp/il2cppOutput" -I"." -I"/Users/db639c/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include" -I"/Users/db639c/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward" -I"/Users/db639c/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/include" -c -g -DNDEBUG -funwind-tables -fno-limit-debug-info -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fno-rtti -std=c++98 -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fno-strict-overflow -fPIC -Os --sysroot "/Users/db639c/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/android-ndk-r16b/sysroot" -gcc-toolchain "/Users/db639c/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64" -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -isystem "/Users/db639c/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/android-ndk-r16b/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi" -D__ANDROID_API__=16 -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon-fp16 -Wno-unused-value "/Users/db639c/Desktop/Projects/Unity 10ft/Data Testing v2/Temp/StagingArea/Il2Cpp/il2cppOutput/Il2CppAttributes.cpp" -o "/Users/db639c/Desktop/Projects/Unity 10ft/Data Testing v2/Library/il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a/il2cpp_cache/F803C2153AA5C985B8E844104B91FF45.o"

   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.BuildAllCppFiles(IEnumerable`1 sourceFilesToCompile, IBuildStatisticsCollector statisticsCollector)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.Build(IBuildStatistics& statistics)
   at il2cpp.Program.DoRun(String[] args)
   at il2cpp.Program.Run(String[] args)
   at il2cpp.Program.Main(String[] args)
stderr:

Unhandled Exception: Unity.IL2CPP.Building.BuilderFailedException: 

Invocation was: Executable: /Users/db639c/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++
Arguments: -DNET_4_0 -DUNITY_AOT -DGC_NOT_DLL -DRUNTIME_IL2CPP -DLINUX -DANDROID -DPLATFORM_ANDROID -D__linux__ -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -I"/Applications/Unity/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/bdwgc/include" -I"/Applications/Unity/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/libil2cpp/include" -I"/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/il2cpp/libil2cpp" -I"/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/il2cpp/external/boehmgc/include" -I"/Users/db639c/Desktop/Projects/Unity 10ft/Data Testing v2/Temp/StagingArea/Il2Cpp/il2cppOutput" -I"." -I"/Users/db639c/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include" -I"/Users/db639c/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/backward" -I"/Users/db639c/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi-v7a/include" -c -g -DNDEBUG -funwind-tables -fno-limit-debug-info -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wa,--noexecstack -fno-rtti -std=c++98 -fno-strict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fno-strict-overflow -fPIC -Os --sysroot "/Users/db639c/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/android-ndk-r16b/sysroot" -gcc-toolchain "/Users/db639c/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64" -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -isystem "/Users/db639c/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/android-ndk-r16b/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi" -D__ANDROID_API__=16 -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon-fp16 -Wno-unused-value "/Users/db639c/Desktop/Projects/Unity 10ft/Data Testing v2/Temp/StagingArea/Il2Cpp/il2cppOutput/Il2CppAttributes.cpp" -o "/Users/db639c/Desktop/Projects/Unity 10ft/Data Testing v2/Library/il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a/il2cpp_cache/F803C2153AA5C985B8E844104B91FF45.o"

   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.BuildAllCppFiles(IEnumerable`1 sourceFilesToCompile, IBuildStatisticsCollector statisticsCollector)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.Build(IBuildStatistics& statistics)
   at il2cpp.Program.DoRun(String[] args)
   at il2cpp.Program.Run(String[] args)
   at il2cpp.Program.Main(String[] args)
   at Program.Main(String[] args)

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner:RunProgram(Program, String, String, String, CompilerOutputParserBase) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:128)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner:RunNetCoreProgram(String, String, String, CompilerOutputParserBase, Action`1) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:79)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:RunIl2CppWithArguments(List`1, Action`1, String) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:366)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:ConvertPlayerDlltoCpp(String, String, String, Boolean) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:349)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:Run() (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:211)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils:RunIl2Cpp(String, String, IIl2CppPlatformProvider, Action`1, RuntimeClassRegistry) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:35)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

ERROR 2:

```
Exception: /Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/il2cpp/build/il2cppcore/il2cppcore.dll did not run properly!
UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunProgram (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:130)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner.RunNetCoreProgram (System.String exe, System.String args, System.String workingDirectory, UnityEditor.Scripting.Compilers.CompilerOutputParserBase parser, System.Action`1[T] setupStartInfo) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:79)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.RunIl2CppWithArguments (System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] arguments, System.Action`1[T] setupStartInfo, System.String workingDirectory) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:366)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.ConvertPlayerDlltoCpp (System.String inputDirectory, System.String outputDirectory, System.String workingDirectory, System.Boolean platformSupportsManagedDebugging) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:349)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder.Run () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:211)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils.RunIl2Cpp (System.String tempFolder, System.String stagingAreaData, UnityEditorInternal.IIl2CppPlatformProvider platformProvider, System.Action`1[T] modifyOutputBeforeCompile, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry runtimeClassRegistry) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:35)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.RunIl2Cpp.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <62f761e6ab1445a38cdcb4ac36512695>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <62f761e6ab1445a38cdcb4ac36512695>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <62f761e6ab1445a38cdcb4ac36512695>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <62f761e6ab1445a38cdcb4ac36512695>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:286)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

Answer (score 3):

For those facing this issue, it was caused by Catalina not allowing some scripts to run because of the new security features.  I fixed it by re-installing the r16 NDK, going to Security & Privacy, and making sure that every time I encountered the "[script name] blocked from running" errors after pressing BUILD in unity, that I click the "Allow Anyway..." button in Security & Privacy BEFORE clicking either "Cancel" or "Open" on the error modals.

The build will fail several times, but it will ask for new permissions every time for new scripts, and eventually it will get through all scripts needed and the build will succeed.

Comment: Months of trying to fix it and this actually helped! Thanks